# VB6 mySQL update problem

Tags: vb6, mysql

Hey all, i am having a weird problem with trying to update a record in my mySQL 5 database using VB6.

This is my code when i log in:

```
connDB
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT id, fName, lName, theCode, theDate, clockin FROM clockinout WHERE theCode = '" & theUsersUniqueID & "' AND theDate = '" & Format(Now, "YYYY/MM/DD") & "'"
          rst.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

If rst.EOF Then
    rst.AddNew
    rst!FName = userFNmae
    rst!LName = userLName
    rst!theCode = theUsersUniqueID
    rst!theDate = Format(Now, "YYYY/MM/DD")
    rst!clockin = Format(Now, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS")
Else
    rst!clockin = Format(Now, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS")
End If

rst.Update
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
conn.Close
```

This works just fine without any errors. However, when i log out using this code:

```
 connDB
 Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

 strSQL = "SELECT id, fName, lName, theCode, theDate, clockout FROM clockinout WHERE theCode = '" & theUsersUniqueID & "' AND theDate = '" & Format(Now, "YYYY/MM/DD") & "'"
 rst.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

 If Not rst.EOF Then
     rst!clockout = Format(Now, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS")
 End If

 rst.Update
 rst.Close
 Set rst = Nothing
 conn.Close
```

It comes out with an error saying its EOF since it can not find the record for some reason... Its in there because it worked on the first login. Strangely, when i take out **clockout** and replace it with **clockin** it **FINDS THE RECORD** but can not update it since rst!clockout was not in the query!!!! But when i **do** put it back into the query in place of clockin, it gives me the EOF error....

My database record looks like this:

```
 ID | fName | lName  | theCode | theDate    | clockin             | clockout         |
 26  Bob     Barker   5810      2010/08/02   2010-08-02 02:44:28   0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Any help would be great as i have no idea why this simple update is giving me such a hard time..

David

**I have also tested the query in the mysql query browser and all works fine...**

SELECT id, fName, lName, theCode, theDate, clockin, clockout FROM clockinout WHERE theCode = '5810' AND theDate = '2010/08/02';

Comment: In your first example, when you have no row, you are filling in all the columns and then using `UPDATE`. Does this update create a row? I'm not sure it does; and if it doesn't it might appear to succeed but have updated no rows. But my knowledge of ADO was mainly gleaned from those two excellent tutors, Mr Copy and Mr Paste, so take this suggestion for whatever it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that all you'll need is to add `clockout` in your original query, but it shouldn't be replacing `clockin`.  You don't have to do anything with `clockout` until you reach the log out section, but it does need to be in the query from the start.

**EDIT:** Based on the error you gave in your comment, it sounds like the problem lies in the existing value for clockout in your database.  I think `0000-00-00 00:00:00` might be the source of the problem; try using some other date, or using `NULL` instead.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,49727,54030#msg-54030

Comment: When i add both clockin and clockout to the original query i get this when trying to log in **Data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status**

But when i take out the clockout in the query, it works on the login...

Comment: @StealthRT - Just added some info to my answer based on your error message - I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

id is a reserved word, the sql browser "helps" with the syntax from the user, always use brackets [id] in the code when column naming is in conflict with reserved words